# How to graphically find integral of square of signal.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Say we have a signal $x(t)$, then integral of $x(t)$ is the area under the curve. But integral of $x^2(t)$ is not simply square of that area!

Is there any way to graphically find integral of $x^2(t)$? For any $x(t)$.

Comment: You need to integrate, there is no shorter method imo

Comment: No, I believe its impossible to do in general.